# Any idea what I should pay for a nyatiti?

Tags: string-instruments, african

There aren't any available to try in my area, but I'd really like to pick one up.  The thing is, I have no idea what a reasonable price is.  There are a few online, but the prices vary (in one case, it looks like the same instrument is for sale for two wildly different prices, one at about $100 and the other site at about $500).

Basically, I've loved the first Ayub Ogada record for almost 30 years, and I want to make that noise. If anyone could point me in the right-ish direction, I'd appreciate it.

Some links:

http://bideetmusique.cdandlp.com/item/2/0-1916-0-1-0/117657503/kenyan-african-luo-traditional-instrument-nyatiti.html (Jojo records, $500)

http://www.groovecollector.com/mp/kenyan-african-luo-traditional-instrument-nyatiti/r/117657505/ (Also Jojo records, $100)

And so on, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The price will vary based on who is trying to sell it to you and the age and condition of the instrument. Unfortunately, there is just no standard price.

They are hard to get. If you have connections and can do some travelling you can get one for $30. If you want one shipped to you from Nairobi you should expect to pay $300 or so.

Quality varies widely for things available online. There is a lot of tourist junk available that is listed as a nyatiti but is really just an ornament.

If you want, I might be able to help you get one.